# Android: Make a part of TextView's text NOT-clickable at runtime?

Tags: android, onclick, clickable, spannablestring, spannable

I used `Android.text.style.ClickableSpan` to make a part (`Black`) of a string (`Blue | Black`)  clickable:

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("Blue | Black ");
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        //...
    }
};
ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 7, 11, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secondActivity_textView4);
textView.setText(spannableString);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

So `Black` part of the string is clickable. What I want is that when the user clicks `Black`, it should make `Black` Not-clickable, and `Blue` (another part of the same string) clickable.

**So to make `Blue` clickable, we can call `setSpan()` on the same `spannableString` another time. But how can I make `Black` not-clickable?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`removeSpan()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html#removeSpan%28java.lang.Object%29) to remove any previously added Spans. In this particular case it's very easy, as we hold a reference to the very Span we want to remove:

```
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        ((SpannableString)textView.getText()).removeSpan(this);
    }
};
```

Another option could be to iterate over all `ClickableSpan` instances and remove them all, such as:

```
    SpannableString str = (SpannableString)textView.getText();
    for (ClickableSpan span : str.getSpans(0, str.length(), ClickableSpan.class))
        str.removeSpan(span);
```

For some reason that I cannot fathom, the documentation for spans is really poor... they are quite powerful!